# Какую технологию выбрать для реализации асинхроного клиента серверного веб-приложения?

Tags: node.js, ajax, php, javascript, база-данных

**Задача:**
1. Сайт, на котором совершается продажа билетов по местам, проданные места, к примеру, закрашиваются красным.
2. Клиент, который устанавливается на кассы тоже в виде сайта на локальном сервере. 
Клиент нужен для того, чтобы выполнять команды в командной строке клиента (кстати, если это можно как-то обойти, то совет бы не помешал, то есть с основного сайта выполнять команды на клиентах).

**Вопрос:**
Как сделать так, чтобы при продаже билета на сервере у клиента автоматически без перезагрузки страницы место закрасилось красным? Посоветуйте нужные связки технологий.

Comment: По-хорошему такое делается через websockets (а это практически сразу же node.js), но, насколько знаю, пока они еще не всеми поддерживаются, так что типичным решением будет ajax + long polling на любой платформе (если планы проекта позволяют ему обновиться через года три - берите сразу ноду, наверное, если нет - то, на чем умеете писать). Вообще набор технологий, реазулиющих близкую к реалтаймовой асинхронщину, называют comet, если будет интересно почитать про картину в целом.

> Клиент нужен для того, чтобы выполнять команды в командной строке клиента.

Вот это не понял, если честно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду исследовать.
Насчет командной строки: на кассах стоят термопринтеры которые печатают на билетах переменные данные. Чтобы отправить задание на печать, нужно сформировать файл на языке программирования принтера и отправить на lpt-порт принтера. Из за этого приходится писать клиент, то есть если бы это можно было делать через основной сайт, тогда клиент бы не понадобился.

Comment: @Metric, боюсь, это невозможно без стороннего приложения. Либо это веб-сервер с вашим приложением, которое тянет командную строку, либо какое-то другое, управляемое по сети, которое занимается тем же и может быть написано так же на чем угодно. Я бы по максимуму использовал текущую инфраструктуру.

Answer (score 1):

**Задача 1**

**Вариант 1**  
Node.JS + socket.io

Socket.io кроссбраузерная библиотечка, включающая поддержку WebSockets. Для старых браузеров будет использовать ajax + long (low) polling, iframe и т.д.

**Вариант 2**
Пишем ручками

Примерно то же самое, что и выше, только написанное ручками. 
Клиент заходит на страницу, создается соединение с сервером.

По интервалу оно разрывается и пересоздается.

На сервере когда срабатывает нужное действие - оправляются данные по каналу созданному выше.

Подробнее можно прочесть тут: [Цикл статей про comet на javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet)